# Trying to UPDATE one table from another in SQL - returns "more than one value" error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know this looks like a duplicate, but I've been working through similar-looking questions and still I can't get past this error.

I can't understand why this SQL UPDATE query returns a "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error.

```
UPDATE ph
SET ph.manufacturerPartNumber = t.DocID
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN PartHeader ph ON ph.partID = t.partID
```

The data involved is below.

```
SELECT t.partID,t.DocID,ph.partID,ph.manufacturerPartNumber
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN PartHeader ph ON ph.partID = t.partID
```

[image]

I don't understand where the "more than 1 value" is coming from. Each partID from t has exactly 1 partID in ph.

I've also tried the following with the same error.

```
UPDATE PartHeader
SET PartHeader.manufacturerPartNumber = (SELECT t.DocID
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN PartHeader ph ON ph.partID = t.partID)
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm sure missing it.

Thanks for your help,
Dan

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Your first update query looks fine. `"Subquery returned more than 1 value"` this error message should be from your second update query, isn't it?? or do you get same error message from both UPDATE queries?

Comment: Both queries give the same error.

Comment: Is `PartHeader` a table or a view?

Comment: PartHeader is a table.

Comment: It would be easy, if you create both tables on sql-fiddle and add above data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you're sure that the SQL you've written is fine, I'd like to suggest that perhaps you have an ON UPDATE/AFTER UPDATE trigger on the table which was not written to handle more than one row being updated at once.

This could be quickly validated by disabling any of the update related triggers, and trying to run your update again.

Edit:

If you do disable a trigger whilst testing this, please make sure you re-enable it later. You can't guarantee an update will only affect one row, so you'll need to fix the trigger - assuming you want whatever process the trigger is for (auditing perhaps?) to continue.

Comment: @kaf it willl error the update query as it is part of the transaction.

Comment: @kaf, your orginal code does not have a subquery, so the chances are really good that it is a trigger.

Comment: @HLGEM, 100% agreed, as I commented on the OP, first query has no subquery. This is most likely to be the reason.

Comment: I would even be willing to guess that they are setting some scalar value witha  query from inserted or delted that contains more than one record and that is where the error comes from. triggers should alawys be written to handle mulitple record inserts/updates/deletes and should be tested with such.

Comment: By the way @HLGEM, question is not mine...;)

Comment: @HLGEM Exactly my thinking.

Comment: Sorry @kaf, didn't scroll up. The OPs orginal code does not contain a subquery.

Comment: @Bridge - You're my hero. That was exactly it. There was an update trigger on the PartHeader table. Disabling that allowed my query to complete without error.

Comment: @DanNorton It was from experience - badly designed triggers have got me before. Glad I could help.

Comment: Do not disable triggers, fix them if they are broken.

Comment: @HLGEM I couldn't agree more - I only suggested it as a quick way to validate that a trigger was in fact the cause. I made the usual assumptions - that you would re-enable triggers afterwards, this wasn't a live production database etc. If you blindly follow the advice of people on the internet without testing things yourself first, you're an idiot IMHO!

Comment: Sadly I have sen too many times where people say, "this trigger isn't working, I'll just disable it" and then wonder later what happened to some data that is needed that should have populated by the trigger.

Comment: @HLGEM Alas I have too. I've edited my answer to include your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your results aren't working.  Your 2nd query could produce the error you listed above if your Temp table returns multiple DocIds per PartId.  However, your first query should work.

See this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d34b/1

SQL Server will just skip the duplicated records and update accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't help either. I believe I started that way.

Comment: Hmmm -- something about your temp table maybe -- this works in this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d18a/1...

Comment: @DanNorton -- not sure what's going on -- I could see you getting that error with your 2nd query since the temp table has multiple records -- but the first query (or my above query) should work unless there's something else going on...

Answer (score 0):

The query that you are using below returns more than one one row.

```
SELECT t.partID,t.DocID,ph.partID,ph.manufacturerPartNumber
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN PartHeader ph ON ph.partID = t.partID
```

So when you try to do this

```
UPDATE ph
SET ph.manufacturerPartNumber = t.DocID
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN PartHeader ph ON ph.partID = t.partID
```

you dont have a single t.DocID since there are multiple rows being returned from #tmp. So make sure that the R.H.S of the `=` in your update returns only one value

Comment: I agree with this -- but it still works -- SQL Server just skips the 2nd record.  Here is a sample fiddle with what I mean: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d2348/1 -- very strange...

Comment: But partID is unique in both tables. This is real data and what I've shown includes the entire #tmp table while partID is the key of PartHeader.

Answer (score 0):

If you are convinced that the subquery does not contain duplicate rows, try changing this:

```
UPDATE PartHeader
SET PartHeader.manufacturerPartNumber = (SELECT t.DocID
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN PartHeader ph ON ph.partID = t.partID)
```

to this:

```
UPDATE PartHeader
SET PartHeader.manufacturerPartNumber = (SELECT max(t.DocID)
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN PartHeader ph ON ph.partID = t.partID)
```

However, if this was my problem, I'd be querying my temp table some more rather than simply assuming that I am smarter than the software.

Comment: This query also gives "Subquery returned more than 1 value"